# find wheher string value is integer or decimal kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, math, integer, decimal-point

I have dynamic string value which i get from server response ( eg: a = 18 or a = 18.75) . I need to find whether a value has decimal point or not in kotlin. i need to display it in discount_price

```
if(product[position].discounted_price.) {
            mrp.text = "₹" + product.get(position).price
            mrp.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            sellingprice.text = "₹" + product.get(position).discounted_price
            tv_cartvariant.text = variant.cart_count.toString()
        } else {
            mrp.text = "₹" + product.get(position).price + ".00"
            mrp.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            sellingprice.text = "₹" + product.get(position).discounted_price + ".00"
            tv_cartvariant.text = variant.cart_count.toString()
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%.2f".format(price.toDouble())` automatically formats the price with 2 decimal places.
Examples:

- `"%.2f".format(2.toDouble())` returns `2.00`
- `"%.2f".format(2.36.toDouble())` returns `2.36`
- `"%.2f".format(2.9244.toDouble())` returns `2.92`
- `"%.2f".format(2.1093.toDouble())` returns `2.11`

Comment: @SasidharanIOS Please mark the question as solved when you have the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then try:

```
if(product[position].discounted_price.toString().contains('.') {
    // price has decimal dot
} else {
    // price is probably integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to show prices with 2 decimal places, this can be done as following, no need to check for dot

```
mrp.text = "₹" + "%.2f".format(product.get(position).price.toDouble())
mrp.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
sellingprice.text = "₹" + "%.2f".format(product.get(position).discounted_price.toDouble())
tv_cartvariant.text = variant.cart_count.toString()
```